# "It's around evening" is it correct to use

Tags: spoken-english

I was chatting with one of my overseas friends:

> My friend: Is it evening over there.
>
> I: It's **around** evening here.

I want to express that **it's not evening right now but very soon.**

Did I answer correctly.

Please explain

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Around", when used about times, means "approximately". If a period of time has not yet arrived, but will soon, it might be better to use 'nearly'.

> It's nearly evening here.

Comment: *Almost* could also be used. Note that both *nearly* and *almost* (by their usage) imply that it will be even soon. With *around*, the interpretation is more ambiguous (because it's not normally used). It could also apply if evening had just *passed*, and the sky was starting to get light again.